# android - showing rewarded video ads after click list

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob

I have a list of items at homepage and when clicked will go to the activity detail. Before that I want to add `Rewarded Video Ads`, but with a limit after the user 3x click on the item list the ads will appear.
Any suggestions for making it like that?
or Similar features of `Shared Preferences` maybe?

UPDATE:
I have try to run with below code, but this does not count every list that is clicked..

```
class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView tvTitle;
        private LinearLayout rowLayout;

        ViewHolder(View itemView, final Context ctx) {
            super(itemView);
            mContext = ctx;
            tvTitle = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            rowLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rowLayout);

               itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               int clickCount = 1;
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v){
                        if(clickCount > 3) {

                          if(mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()){
                            mRewardedVideoAd.show();
                        }
                            clickCount = 0;
                        } else {

                            clickCount++;
                        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, DetailsActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("title", dataList.get(getAdapterPosition()));
                        intent.putExtra("preview", previewList.get(getAdapterPosition()));
                        ctx.startActivity(intent);

                        }
                    }
                  }
                 }
                });
```

It should apply to all every clicked lists, not just for the list per item counted.

Comment: Do you mean that after  clicks from the user the ad will disappear or the opposite ?

Comment: @TamirAbutbul User must at least click on the 3x list of items, when the '4th' click and then rewarded video ads will appear. then so on

Comment: I could not get you all the way - are we talking about the same view? or view in a  list ?

Comment: @TamirAbutbul not the same view.

in the list at the homepage, after the user clicks he will go to the detail activity of the item.

before going to item details, I will place the video ads there but after he visits 3 items (3 clicks) on the list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated:**

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v){
int clickCount = mPreference.getInt("count",0);
                        if(clickCount > 3) {

                          if(mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()){
                            mRewardedVideoAd.show();

                        }
                             mPreference.edit().remove("count").apply();

                        } else {

                            clickCount++;
mPreference.edit().putInt("count",clickCount).apply();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, DetailsActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("title", dataList.get(getAdapterPosition()));
                        intent.putExtra("preview", previewList.get(getAdapterPosition()));
                        ctx.startActivity(intent);

                        }
                    }
                  });
```

Why don't you use custom interface in your ViewHolder class rather than doing this !

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this code :

```
     Button button = findViewById(R.id.button_id);
     int click = 0 ;
     button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
            if(click > 3){
            //show ads
            }else{
             click++ ;
            }
         PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this)
        .edit().putString(key, value).apply();

         }
     });
```

Comment: I try this its work, but this does not count every list that is clicked.
It should apply to all every clicked lists, not just for the list per item counted.
Check my updated code

Comment: If all of your lists are in the same activity and "click" is global variable than it should work  - if this is not the case let me know and i will change my answer accordingly

Comment: Yeahh sir, the code works for the case you say that. But now, I want to implement it on the RecyclerView adapter like the code above.

Calculating is successful, it will only count on one clicked list (item) if if I click on another item, the value does not add to the previous one, but adding to start from 0 according to the position of the item, thank you,